# How can I fix multiple columns of in two rows in the Datatable?

Tags: javascript, html, css, datatable, datatables

I am using the datatable, I have 2 rows in the thead and I want to apply fixedColumns logic to that 2 rows using datatable.

[image]

data with :Updated a year ago, 414,204, ...." is row 1 and data with "#, AA, BB, ....." columns is row 2.

I want first 7 columns to be fixed in the 2 header rows of the table i.e., till FF column in the second row.

I want the 7 columns of first 2 rows should be fixed while Scrolling the table from right to left and left to right.